# Special Case of famous Equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I'm interested in the following diophantine eqaution: $(5^n-1)/4=y^2$.

It turns out that this is a special case of the Nagell-Ljunggren equation, where $x=5$ and $q=2$

It has been shown that for x=5 this has no solutions but I'm looking for an elementary solution of this special case.

Comment: First, you say that there are no solutions, but $(n,y)=(1,\pm1)$ are solutions. Second, did you try factoring $5^n=(2y)^2+1$ as 
$ (2+i)^n(2-i)^n = (2y+i)(2y-i)$? This might lead to an elementary proof (if you consider using the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a PID elementary).

Comment: I was referring to non-trivial solutions. Besides $(n,y)=(1,±1)$ are always solutions of the Nagell-Ljunggren diophantine.

Comment: When writing something mathematical, it's always best to be precise, since the reader may not be able to guess what you mean. So if you mean "no non-trivial solutions", then that's what you should write. (I hope that you will take this as the constructive criticism that it's meant to be. I'm paraphrasing advice that I give to my PhD students; that they should always proofread what they've written as if they are someone seeing the material for the first time. So every statement needs to be precise.)

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your advice sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of problem usually requires a little algebraic number theory. Joe Silverman sketches one possible approach in the comments. Here is another. Let's rewrite as
$$
(2y)^2-5^n=-1.
$$
If $n$ is even then the left-hand side is a difference of two squares, which quickly gives a contradiction. So write $n=2m+1$. Then
$$
(2y+5^m \sqrt{5})(2y-5^m \sqrt{5})=-1.
$$
Thus $2y+5^m \sqrt{5}$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$. A fundamental unit is $\epsilon=(-1+\sqrt{5})/2$. It follows that
$$
2y+5^m \sqrt{5}=\pm \epsilon^{t}.
$$
Conjugating 
$$
2y-5^m \sqrt{5}=\pm \mu^t, \qquad \mu=(-1+\sqrt{5})/2.
$$
Taking differences and dividing by $\pm  \sqrt{5}$ we have
$$
\pm 2 \cdot 5^m= \frac{\epsilon^t-\mu^t}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$
The right-hand side is the $t$-th Fibonacci number. Thus the equation becomes
$$
F_t=\pm 2 \cdot 5^m.
$$
Let's rule out the case $m \ge 1$, which leaves you with $F_t= \pm 2$. If $m \ge 1$ then $F_t \equiv 0 \pmod{10}$. Now write out the Fibonacci sequence modulo $10$ and convince yourself that this forces $t \equiv 0 \pmod{15}$. But then $F_{15} \mid F_t$. However, $F_{15}=2 \cdot 5 \cdot 61$, which does not divide $2 \cdot 5^m$, giving a contradiction.